# Who to call to fix electric oven?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, appliances, oven

My electric oven stopped heating. The range works fine. The digital controls work fine. The oven light works fine. But neither the element at the bottom of the oven nor the one at the top heat up at all.
I've run my fingers over both elements, and there don't seem to be any burnt or rough spots.

At this point, I have no idea what to do. And I don't even know whom to call.  An electrician?  A handyman?  Or would it be cheaper just to buy a new oven?

The oven was here when I bought the house several years ago, so I don't have the manual or know where they got it.

If anyone has any advice, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: what's the brand, model and make?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Turns out, there is a sticker with a phone number to call on the inside of the drawer. I tested the elements, and they're fine.  Tested the temperature probe, and it's fine. All I can think is that the door isn't registering as shut, but I can't find a latch or a switch or anything... so I can't figure out what to do about it.  So, off to call someone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I would check the circuit breaker, flip it off and back on then re check oven. If it does not work think about what you have done since last you used it, are you sure the door is latching closed and the controlls are on the right position?  If you know someone who has lived in the area for a long time ask them if they know who to call. An electrican can fix it. Call any local appliance sales place and ask for a recomendation on who to call.

Answer (score 4):

If the stove top is working you are getting power.The person you want to call is a large appliance repair shop.They will be able to diagnose the problem, give you an estimate and hopefully give you an honest opinion if the repair is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the model/serial number of your oven usually etched on a metal plate around the oven door or inside the oven.

The easiest way is to call the manufacturer and they will recommend a service provider for you.

Keep in mind that average service calls (assuming the appliance is no longer under warranty) is gonna be in the hundreds.

Depending on the value of your range/oven, it may make sense to simply replace it with a new one.

Best of luck.

Comment: The original question was in 2012, think they may have solved it already?

Comment: Good point.  Just realized that the original question was from 2012 - it showed up on the top of home page feed since someone wrote something to this post an hour ago.  But in case another person has the same question - I hope what I posted helps.

Comment: It showed at the top because 1 managed to answer instead of posting their own question...

Comment: @SolarMike It's fine to give a good answer to an old question; the goal is to accumulate knowledge.